# Copy Data from multiple excel files to existing file on specific sheet

Tags: python, pandas, openpyxl

I would like to copy the data from multiple excel files and paste it existing excel file.

```
import os
import openpyxl
import pandas as pd

my_path = r'C://Users//greencolor//Autoreport//Load_attachments//' # Updating every monday with new files
my_path1 =r'C://Users//greencolor//Desktop//Autoreport//' # place of Master.xlsx 
for filename in os.listdir(my_path): #loop though the downloaded files 
    if filename.startswith('PB orders Dec'): #finds the file with the name PB orders December.xlsb
        dec = pd.read_excel(os.path.join(my_path, filename), 
                                         sheet_name='Raw data ', 
                                         engine='pyxlsb') #reading the specific sheet named Raw data
        with pd.ExcelWriter(my_path1 + '//Maaster.xlsx', mode='a', engine=openpyxl) as writer:
            dec.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='DecData', index=False) #copyes the data from PB orders December.xlsb and paste it in Master file on sheet Decdata without deleting other sheets. Basically updating all data with new data.
```

**My problem** is that I would like to do the same above mentioned operation on multiple files. For example, if in the `Load_attachments` is the file named PB orders November.xlsb  I want to apply the same code to that November file and so on what ever month name file has.

Comment: Just put the entire thing (minus imports) in a for loop and feed it with an array of filenames?

Comment: Sorry can  you elaborate or show  the example?

Comment: Okay, let me write an answer

Answer (score 0):

You can put the entire thing (minus imports) in a for loop and feed it with an array of filename beginnings:

```
import os
import openpyxl
import pandas as pd

fnamebegin_array = ['PB orders Jan','PB orders Feb','PB orders Mar','etc']
sheetname_array = ['JanData','FebData','MarData','etc']

for i in range(len(fnamebegin_array)): # would be 12, if there is data for each month in a year
    my_path = r'C://Users//greencolor//Autoreport//Load_attachments//'
    my_path1 =r'C://Users//greencolor//Desktop//Autoreport//'
    for filename in os.listdir(my_path):
        if filename.startswith(fnamebegin_array[i]):
            month = pd.read_excel(os.path.join(my_path, filename), 
                                         sheet_name='Raw data ', 
                                         engine='pyxlsb')
            with pd.ExcelWriter(my_path1 + '//Master.xlsx', mode='a', engine=openpyxl) as writer:
                month.to_excel(writer, sheet_name=sheetname_array[i], index=False)
```

Comment: It only reads January file and skips other files

Comment: If there are e.g. December files, you have to add the entry on fnamebegin_array and a corresponding sheet name on sheetname_array.

Comment: Yes, I do have them. All 12 months